# Automatic Notifications

Tags: support, notifications

Is there a way for me to get auto email notifications for new responses or comments to my questions/answers/comments? Surely there is a better way than constantly refreshing every so often? :-)

Comment: Did you look at your profile? There's a "prefs" link that has an option which might do what you want.

Comment: Oh! Thank you I handnt noticed that button.

Comment: @DylanMoreland please consider adding an actual answer instead of just a comment! (:  (Also note that you can set these prefs at the bottom of any question you've asked)

Comment: @Dylan I am not sure that this is exactly what OP is asking about. IIRC allowing notifications in your preferences will lead to getting one email per day, in case you have unread notifications in your SE inbox. I think that the OP is asking about immediate notifications, i.e. everything which goes into SE inbox should be sent via email, too. But I might be wrong - perhaps Mohammad could clarify what precisely is he asking about.

Comment: Another alternative: each question has an RSS feed.

Comment: @MartinSleziak You are right - I would like immediate notifications to: 1) Answers to my questions 2) Comments to my questions 3) Comments to my comments, 4) Comments to my answers ...

Answer (score 6):

If I read your question correctly, you'd like to receive email notifications for **new comments or responses to your questions**. look at the following screenshot:

[image: Email notifications]

This is the screen that appears when click on **Ask Question** menu on the main site. So, when you write the question, you may utilise this option to do exactly what you'd want to do: receive email notifications for responses or comments on your question, comments on your answer.

Do note that SE does not clog your inbox by sending you an email every time a new comment/answer is posted. An email is sent if your question has been commented on and no other notifications come till you visit the site (*in response to the email*). However, another notification will follow if your question received an answer. And the same goes for newer answers!

[image: Enter email]

However I am not sure what you'd do, if you asked a question without exercising this option and later you make up your mind. I'll leave this to someone else.

Also, the email preference option Dylan has mentioned in his comments are about receiving mails for questions that come to the site with your favorite tags and I am not sure if this will satisfy your needs.

Comment: Ah thank you Kannappan, I will do so - my email is up for most of the day and it is my one stop shop for any and all notifications for anything. Would this method also work for any comments to answers I leave? Or comments to comments on someone else's questions?

Comment: Yes, your entire unread inbox from MSE will come to your mail's inbox with those restraints I'd written!