# email notifications of activity on questions I am interested in

Tags: support, notifications

I cannot tell if there is a way to get email alerts when there is activity on questions I want to monitor.  Is this possible, and if so how?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Is this along the lines of what you're interested in: [Is there any way to subscribe to a thread so you get email notifications?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21214) This might also be related: [Automatic Notifications](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3710). Or are you interested in something like new questions in specific tags or something completely different?

Comment: A related Meta StackExchange post is [Does StackExchange have email notification option?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122320/does-stack-exchange-have-email-notification-option)

Comment: @martin-sleziak Thanks!  The accepted answer in your first link was exactly what I needed:  I have chosen the daily notification option.